# Password Hashing

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a registration form where the input data is written into the database. The password 'pw' will be hashed with BCRYPT, this works correctly with this code:

$pwHash = pw_hash($pw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));

**Problem:**

When I want to update the data it will not work.
The code below writes the data without encryption into the database.

How can I make the password encrypted?

Can anyone help me out here?

```css
<?php
include_once 'dbcon.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$fn = $_POST['fn'];
$ln = $_POST['ln'];
$em = $_POST['em']; 
$hid = $_POST['hid']; 
$tn = $_POST['tn'];
$us = $_POST['us'];
$pw = $_POST['pw'];
$ul = $_POST['ul'];

$chk = $_POST['chk'];
$chkcount = count($id);
for($i=0; $i<$chkcount; $i++)

$pwHash = pw_hash($pw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));

{
 $MySQLiconn->query("UPDATE user SET FName='$fn[$i]', LName='$ln[$i]', Email='$em[$i]', HerbalifeID='$hid[$i]', TelNr='$tn[$i]', UplineS='$us[$i]', Password='$pwHash[$i]', UserLevel='$ul[$i]'  WHERE UserID=".$id[$i]);
}
header("Location: indexAdmin.php");
?>
```

Comment: Braces (`{...}` ) around blocks of code (for the `if` block?); looks like a fault in your logic

Comment: `$pwHash` isn't an array, it's a string; but you query block is trying to reference it as though it was an array.... as `$pwHash` is a string, `$pwHash[0]` will reference the first character of `$pwHash`; `$pwHash[1]` will reference the second character, etc

Comment: Why are your `$_POST['id']`, `$fn = $_POST['fn'];`, `$em = $_POST['em'];`, etc all being treated as arrays anyway?

Comment: @MarkBaker `$_POST['id']` might be an array if there inputs with names like `id[0]`, `id[1]`, etc. In this case array is created for `id` property in `$_POST` variable.

Comment: @VictorSmirnov - They may well be arrays; though quite why they should be is beyond me unless an individual user can register themselves with multiple accountsin one go..... but the braces and the issue with $pwHash being a string still remain

Answer (score 0):

I guess the fix should be the following

```
<?php
include_once 'dbcon.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$fn = $_POST['fn'];
$ln = $_POST['ln'];
$em = $_POST['em'];
$hid = $_POST['hid'];
$tn = $_POST['tn'];
$us = $_POST['us'];
$pw = $_POST['pw'];
$ul = $_POST['ul'];

$chk = $_POST['chk'];
$chkcount = count($id);
for ($i = 0; $i < $chkcount; $i++) {

    $pwHash = password_hash($pw[$i], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
    $MySQLiconn->query("UPDATE user SET FName='$fn[$i]', LName='$ln[$i]', Email='$em[$i]', HerbalifeID='$hid[$i]', TelNr='$tn[$i]', UplineS='$us[$i]', Password='$pwHash', UserLevel='$ul[$i]'  WHERE UserID=".$id[$i]);
}
header("Location: indexAdmin.php");
```

The changes are

1. Create `pwHash` variable and update table inside the same loop.
2. Access `$pw[$i]` as other variables like `$id` and `$fn` - they all appears to be arrays.
3. `$pwHash` is not an array, access it like a scalar variable.
4. Use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function - update based on comment by [Paul Crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3942918/paul-crovella)

There are several issues related with the code. And primary one I believe is the fact that the code is opened to [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Hello Victor,

Thank you for your comment! 

I become an Fatal error: Call to undefined function pw_hash() at line 17

Regars, Benny

Comment: @Benny you are welcome. Does it work for you? Do you have any questions?

Comment: @benny - well `pw_hash()` was the name of the function your question said you were using, so if that's causing an error now, it should always have been causing an error

Comment: Everything is working!

I thought that pw_hash was related to the variable pw, but changed pw_hash to password_hash.

Thanks Paul Crovella & Victor Smirnov !

Comment: @Benny great! I've updated the answer with the function name and reference to the comment. I suggest to accept the answer to make sure other people do not spend time on solved questions.